# Calculating runtime minus Timestamp

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have a form which activates a procedure via an "On form submit" trigger. At the end of this routine I want to insert the difference in time between the form's Timestamp and the current time at the end of the routine (the difference of which is only a matter of a few seconds).

I've tried many things so far, but the result I typically receive is NaN.

I thought that my best bet would be to construct the runtime elements (H,M,S) and similarly deconstruct the time elements from the entire Timestamp, and then perform a bit of math on that:

var rt_ts = Math.abs(run_time - ts_time);

(btw, I got that formula from somewhere on this site, but I'm obviously grasping at anything at this point. I just can't seem to find a thread where my particular issue is addressed)

I've always found that dealing with dates and time in Javascript is tricky business (ex: the quirk that "month" start at zero while "date" starts at 1. That's unnecessarily mind-bending). 
Would anyone care to lead me out of my current "grasping" mindset and guide me towards something resembling a logical approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a function which can show the times in a ss with timestamps in column A.  It will also add the time of the script itself to the first timestamp (in row 3) and show this in the Log.

Notice that the google spreadsheet timestamp has a resolution in seconds and the script timestamp in milliseconds.  So if you only add, say, 300 milliseconds to a spreadsheet timestamp, it might not show any difference at all if posted back to a spreadsheet. The script below only takes about 40 milliseconds to run, so I have added a Utilities.sleep(0) where you can change the value 0 to above 1000 to show a difference.

```
function testTime(){
      var start = new Date().getTime();
      var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();
      for(var i = 2; i < values.length ; i++){
      Logger.log(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(values[i][0]),Session.getTimeZone(),'d MMM yy hh:mm:ss' )); // this shows the date, in my case same as the ss timestamp.
      Logger.log(  new Date(values[i][0]).getTime()  ); // this is the date in Milliseconds after 1 Jan 1970
      }

      Utilities.sleep(0); //you can vary this to see the effects

      var endTime = new Date();
      var msCumulative = (endTime.getTime() - start);
      Logger.log(msCumulative);
      var msTot = (msCumulative + new Date(values[2][0]).getTime());
      Logger.log('script length in milliseconds ' + msTot );

      var finalTime = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(msTot), Session.getTimeZone(), 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss');
      Logger.log ( finalTime); //Note that unless you change above to  Utilities.sleep(1000) or greater number , this logged date/time is going  to be identical to the first timestamp since the script runs so quickly, less than 1 second.

    }
```

Comment: As I had mentioned to Serge insas, this is not a start/end runtime calculation that I'm trying to perform. It is simply a calculation that subtracts the Timestamp time from the time at the end of the procees; such as "var diff = NOW() - Timestamp". Since I am using "On form submit" as the trigger for this procedure, the "Start" of the runtime is actually the Timestamp time. The "End" of the runtime is NOW(). I am struggling with understanding how to make that calculation work, since I have thrown so many combinations at those two numbers (date/time) and the best I can get is NaN.

Comment: Well, I didn't mean that function to give you the direct solution, rather that it could possibly give you some results upon the data you have, which are not NaN, so you can see what works and what doesn't. You could prove to yourself and people on the board that there is nothing going on untowards.

Comment: Having said all this, the function above can be modified quickly to give you what you want.  The variable "var start" has been set to the current time at the beginning of the script run. Rather than that if it logically set to zero, i.e.var start = 0 ; THEN change + to a minus in the line: var msTot = (msCumulative + new Date(values[2][0]).getTime()) ; then, will finalTime be an example of what you need? (you might then want to put in a loop to do the same for all your values.)

Comment: I am always grateful for all assistance that is provided, so there is certainly nothing "untoward" going on. My Javascript knowledge is rudimentary, although I've learned a lot here. But this continues to confuse me. I read your explanation and I reviewed your function and I have attempted to glean what I could from it. Unfortunately your knowledge surpasses my ability to break down your formula and understand how to apply it to my issue. That's my failure and not yours. I appreciate your effort, and no, I was not looking for a finished solution. Never have. I'll just mark this as solved.

Comment: I appreciate the follow up, but I still don't understand the process. The Timestamp exists. It's in a format (probably as you indicate in your function - although I haven't been able to discern how to apply it as of this point) and NOW() exists in a different format (apparently), so until I understand how to convert one format to the other (or both to one particular format) I've elected to go with a workaround solution and simply perform the calculation directly on the worksheet with a formula. It's not my desired solution, but I understand it and it works. Thanks for trying. I'm just lost.

Comment: @David : working with relative time values you don't need to take the time zone into account... and the time stamp value is available in the e.values or as named range, no need to read the spreadsheet. Also why the loop if this function is triggered by an onFormSubmit ? only the last value would be of interrest ? or did I miss something in the question ?

Comment: @Serge thanks for the heads up on the e.values[0] ... I did not know this (I'll read the docs!).   I don't use onFormSubmit but get the functionality via 1 minute trigger (now, I do this for historical reasons, since I need fail-safe in that the script will retry even if it fails the first time, and the timer is fail-safe since it will try again after 1 minute ... I don't know about making the onFormSubmit failsafe).  These two points explain why I would have to read the spreadsheet ... but the OP might indeed be better off with your suggestion since it does less work to achieve the same thing

Comment: @Serge ... I might do a loop just to check things out, not as a final answer.  Like the OP, I too find timestamps troublesome. One example: We use European settings in our spreadsheets. Several people sharing and access a ss.  I have created several spreadsheets which have form table rows copied to them, for manual intervention. Unfortunately I have found that they can change their timestamp to US format once the user clicks on the timestamp (maybe to copy the timestamp).  Very strange and annoying "bug/feature".

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add this at the top of your onFormSubmit routine :

```
  UserProperties.setProperty('start',new Date().getTime().toString())
```

and this at the end that will show you the duration in millisecs.

```
var duration = new Date().getTime()-Number(UserProperties.getProperty('start'))
```

---

**EDIT following your comment :**

the time stamp coming from an onFormSubmit event is the first element of the array returned by `e.values` see [docs here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events?hl=en)

so I don't really understand what problem you have ??

something like this below should work

```
var duration = new Date().getTime() - new Date(e.values[0]).getTime();//in millisecs
```

the value being a string I pass it it 'new Date' to make it a date object again. You can easily check that using the logger like this :
`Logger.log(new Date(e.values[0]));//`

It will return a complete date value in the form  **Fri Mar 12 15:00:00 GMT+01:00 2013**

But the values will most probably be the same as in my first suggestion since the TimeStamp is the moment when the function is triggered...

Comment: Perhaps I didn't explain the need correctly (or maybe I over-explained it and muddied the point) but it's not a runtime calculation issue that I'm trying to resolve. The issue that I am having is with subtracting the TIMESTAMP time from the NOW() time at the end of the process. Basically: var diff = Now() - Timestamp. (that is obviously a simplistic and useless calculation shown only for the purpose of clarity)

Comment: my code suggestion makes nothing else : substract the form submission time value (that's actually the timeStamp value) from the NOW value... the second line could be placed anywhere in the code where you need it. Now I added another approach that I hope will be more obvious but must of course be part of the triggered function since its value only exist in the scope of this function execution.

Comment: I think the problem that I have is that I approached this from a very basic concept: =now()-A1. [A1 being the Timestamp] and I tried to apply that basic spreadsheet concept into code form to provide a hard number that could be placed in the ss instead of an entire column of formulas. I truly expected this to be as simple as that. Sadly, I continue to struggle with my inability to "think" in Javascript terms, and it continues to have an adverse affect on my approach and understanding of certain elements. I'll test your code (THANK YOU!) but I've now got new issues that I need to resolve first.